# How to display the entire contents of the a TableView while in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableView controller, and the tableView cells were added statically.

as shown in the image_1 below, I have 18 cells. but the problem I have now is, when I change the screen orientation to Landscape, the simulator can not display the entire cells inside the TableView controller, it displays only 8 cells as shown in image_2.

please let me know how to display all cells while in landscape mode.

**image_1**:

[image]

**image_2**:

[image]

Comment: Scroll your tableview. It is already present.

Comment: set the table view frame within the viewcontroller's view. U must add constraints to the table view. Otherwise the table view's height will be more than view height in landscape mode. so add constraints to the tableview to align the top left right and bottom corners to the superview.

Comment: Either you can decrease the size of table view Cell or you can keep as it is as Table view has scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit all the cells, I think, you can either check the current orientation and decrease the cell heights or You always can use collection view and also change the item sizes relative to orientation.